# Get number of repetitions compiled with number of occurence of a number

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a large file that contains numeric data like this

```
123
124
124
124
126
127
127
```

I want to get total Number of repetitions (counted from each number occurring more than once).
The output should be 5 as (124 is repeating 3 times and 127 two times). I am able to count repetitions using `cat file | sort | uniq -d | wc -l` but it gives output as 2 i.e two numbers are repeated (124 &127) and i want output 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `awk` to count the numbers:

```
sort file | uniq -dc | awk '{n+=$1}END{print n}'
```

Output:

```
5
```

(you don't need `cat` here, as `sort` accepts input)

If your `uniq` does not support `-dc`, then

```
sort file | uniq -c | awk '$1>1{n+=$1}END{print n}'
```

Comment: Thanks. It's useful for me

Comment: Unfortunately, `uniq` on macOS Catalina does not allow specifying both `-c` and `-d` at the same time.

Comment: Then use only -c and add $1>1 to awk

Comment: @OldPro If you're using `brew` you can do `brew search coreutils` and then use `guniq` which accepts `-c` and `-d`

Answer (score 8):

```
awk 'seen[$0]++ {count += (seen[$0]==2 ? 2:1)} END {print count+0}' file
```

If a line has been seen before, increment `count` by either 2 or 1 (based on whether this line is the first duplicate). At the end print `count` (`+0` so that awk prints 0 instead of an empty string in case `count` was never incremented).

Another approach:

```
awk '{count += seen[$0]; seen[$0] = (seen[$0]?1:2)} END {print count}' file
```

Instead of incrementing the seen array value, use the array to provide the amount by which count should be incremented – none the first time a line is seen, 2 for the second occurrence, then 1 for each subsequent duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

Since you tagged your question *linux* you likely have the GNU implementation of `uniq`, which has a `-D` option:

```
   -D     print all duplicate lines
```

So

```
$ sort file | uniq -D | wc -l
5
```

Comment: Cool, didn't think about this ... Better than my answer and should be accepted :-)

Comment: @pLumo yours is more portable though

Answer (score 3):

With **Perl**:

```
perl -lne '
  $k += qw(2 1 0)[++$h{$_}<=>2];
  END { print $k; }
' file
5
```

We can compute the number of `dups` by maintaining a hash counter  keyed on the input line.

The running counter $k is incremented in the amounts of 2, 1, and 0 when the key has been seen twice, more than two times, or the very first time.

Note the three -valued spaceship operator `<=>` which returns - 1,0,+1 upon comparison. See `perldoc perlop` for more clear details.

Note : strip  whitespace(s) if any prior to to run this.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below method

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x,a[x]}}' ppp| awk '$2 >1{sum=sum+$2}END{print sum}'
```

output

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print x,a[x]}}' ppp| awk '$2 >1{sum=sum+$2}END{print sum}'
5
```

Adding Python method

```
#!/usr/bin/python
m=open('ppp','r')
j=[]
f=[]
for i in m:
    if i.strip() not in j:
        j.append(i.strip())

e=open('ppp','r')
for i in e:
    f.append(i.strip())

r=0
for w in j:
    if f.count(w) >1:
        r=r+f.count(w)

print r


output
5
```